# Replace portion of an given Image with specified image data

Tags: java, image-processing, java-2d

I have the following image for example,

[Target Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1ADX.jpg)

what i want to do is

Pick any of the Shape [mostly Rectangle] of this image and pain only that area with some other image data of the same size.

For example

[Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClYMM.jpg)

I want that the above image is used to replace the data of the any of the shape to target image.

I just think the solution as following

> Mark the location and width and height of each shape and give them a
>   unique id Store the Shape metadata in either Array or HashMap
>   Randomly Pick any of the Shape's Metadata  from the Array [at this
>   point we have X,Y and Width and Height of the Shape from the target
>   image ] Open the Target Image using buffered Image traverse through
>   it and compare  the PIXEL location with previously selected shape's
>   metadata if it matches then replace that portion [Pixel Value] with
>   the example image uploaded , before replacing i should resize source image [mostly rectangle] to fit to the target shape of the target image.

**am i going in right direction ?**

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I guess you are heading right. But how are you planning to obtain the shape metadata since some contain textures or they will be predefined?

Comment: @blackSmith the source image is static and same every time so we can capture individual shapes location and width and height from the Phtotoshop or something like that , isn't it ?

Comment: @kiheru i don't have problem with setClip can you elaboarte more ?

Comment: @Mihir : Yes, it will be easier. And scaling of the source image should be done from the lower dimension.

Comment: @blackSmith what would be the next step ?

Comment: Seems that you already have the solution, just needed someone to approve. However better/efficient solutions may exist. But I would have follow the same the approach.